# Bi-directional window cycling on Mac with `⌘ + ~` and without `shift`?

Tags: macos, mac, window-manager, mission-control

Is it possible on Mac when I cycle between same app's windows with `command + tilde` (⌘ + ~), stop/release, and then cycle again -- make it go in opposite direction on the second cycle?

Such that I could cycle between 2 windows without ever having to press shift to go in the opposite direction?

I basically would like to replicate the classic alt + tab behavior on Windows/Linux where you can keep cycling between just 2 windows back and forth by hitting alt + tab once, release, hit alt + tab once, release, etc.

Oftentimes I have to go back and forth between 2 windows when doing work, and having to press `⌘ + ~ + shift` to go in the opposite direction feels very uncomfortable, makes switching fast very inconvenient to me.

Comment: There's no built-in ability to do this. You would need to find third-party software that intercepts the keys and alters the behaviour.

Comment: Cheap workarounds: Put two tabs in one window. Or put the other windows on a different space.